# Bluetooth keyboard stops sending signal after 30 seconds with a pushed key

Tags: windows-7, keyboard, bluetooth

When I push any key on my bluetooth keyboard (silvercrest, a very cheap one) the signal of a pushed key stops when 30 seconds have been passed. I searched over the keyboard configuration (windows 7) and all over the internet, but cannot understand why this happpens.

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

I can think of two reasons.

- To save the battery life.  It would be really annoying if you left  a book on it and then you couldnt use the keyboard after a few hours.
- To not overload the computer it is transmitting to.

A wired mechanical keyboard will let you do this.  I have used a paperclip to hold the Shift key down in the past, for overnight testing.

Comment: Maybe a save battery mode can be the cause. Any idea to avoid that? Or it's maybe a "hardware feature"? It's really annoying playing games with this keyboard, push W to walk and stop walking even when I pushed another keys, it's awful...

Comment: Unless there is a setup option, no.

Comment: @BarragánLouisenbairn most cheaper keyboards tend to just not have any configuration at all (or there would be "gaming" in their name). I checked out some Silvercrest manuals and some tend to have a config software. Check out if yours does. Either way, I have a feeling that the setting you are looking for might not be available. Perhaps if you can contact them, try and ask for a feature. Unless they are using immutable components that cannot get a firmware update, it should be possible. Whether they would be willing to is a totally different thing.

Comment: @Ulterno thanks.